# ResponseValidationError instead of converting int to str

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

After migrating code to fastapi 0.103 (with pydantic 2) I found that `ResponseValidationError` is now raised when integer value is returned for attribute declared as string in response_model. However converting string to integer works find what seems to be quite inconsistent behaviour. See example

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class IntMessage(BaseModel):
    message: int


class StrMessage(BaseModel):
    message: str


#  this one renders '{"message":123}'
@app.get("/str_to_int", response_model=IntMessage)
async def msg_str():
    return {"message": "123"}


# this raises fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError
@app.get("/int_to_str", response_model=StrMessage)
async def msg_int():
    return {"message": 123}
```

Is it explained anywhere in docs? Can I somehow configure it to work like before? I expect that it tries to convert value to string if possible.

Tried to change the `strict` for a `Field` but didn't help.

```
class StrMessage(BaseModel):
    message: str = Field(strict=False)
```

Comment: I always prefer to create the return object directly instead of creating a dictionary.
`return StrMessage(message=123)` instead of `return {"message": 123}`.
 Then you can also be certain that all the correct types are handled, as creating a new object in Pydantic will validate all the types. And I'm not sure how / when / and if Pydantic converts the dictionary to the return type.

Comment: @Jakube thanks for sharing your best practices. I guess the ResponseValidationError will also be raised if use the StrMessage explicitly.
From docs: 
"strings are accepted as-is, int float and Decimal are coerced using str(v), bytes and bytearray are converted using v.decode(), enums inheriting from str are converted using v.value, and all other types cause an error"

Answer (score 0):

After going deeper I found a workaround for my case. Maybe someone will find it useful:

```
class StrMessage(BaseModel):
    message: str | int

    @field_serializer("message")
    def serialize_message(self, message: str | int, _info):
        return str(message)
```